# retriving all rows with maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT state AS ls,count(*) AS total, max(sales) AS ye FROM TABLE
GROUP BY state
```

Then I get the following result:

```
A total ye
----------
a  22   23
b  23   23
c  24   21
d  25   21
```

But I want to display only state having maximum value of `ye`, i.e:

```
A total ye
----------
a  22   23
b  23   23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select state as ls,count(*) as total ,max(sales) as ye from  table    
where sales = (select max(sales) from table)
group by state
```

Comment: The `count(*) as total` values returned for this query are likely to be lower than those in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `HAVING` clause for this, it's similar to `WHERE` Only it's executed after all data is retrieved. You can specify it after group by like:

```
select state as ls,count(*) as total ,max(sales) as ye from  table    
group by state
having count(*) = max(sales)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select state as ls,count(*) as total, max(sales) as ye from  table    
group by state
having max(sales) = (select max(sales) from table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select * from (select state as ls,count(*) as total ,max(sales) as ye from  table    
group by state)temp HAVING max( ye );
```